# How to extract content of an email from Outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook

I need to write a program that extracts contents of email messages with specific subjects and saves in a text file. Where do I start? Which language has the necessary support?

Comment: Outlook specifically, or Exchange?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming .NET:

- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx)

  - [Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folderclass.aspx) to go through inbox
  - [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitemclass.aspx) to read the message, specifically:

    - [.Subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitemclass.subject.aspx)
    - [.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitemclass.saveas.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can interoperate with Outlook from C++ or [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28VS.71%29.aspx) languages using [Outlook's COM+ interface](http://www.olivierlanglois.net/Outlook_Automation_with_cpp_3.html).

You can find more information at [Microsoft's Outlook Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905455).

Answer (score 0):

I'm lazy and like to go with VBA.  If you like VBA, you can find the references below for most of what you need:

- Folder.Items to get the items- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864247.aspx

  - .MailItem - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx

    - .Subject - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865652.aspx
    - .Body - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304.aspx
    - .SaveAs to save the message as a document - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727.aspx